# While running program in Ubuntu 18.04 (Running inside VMWare) am getting this error: AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Tags: python, vmware, ubuntu-18.04, torchvision

Even though i installed torchvision and cuda successfuly, am getting this error: Am running the program inside VMWare (Ubuntu 18.04).

```
python3 ./decode/train_dataloader.py --img_data ./datasets/image_fmri --output ./tmp/feat_data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./decode/train_dataloader.py", line 26, in <module>
    net = torchvision.models.vgg19_bn(pretrained=True).cuda()
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 260, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 187, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 187, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 193, in _apply
    param.data = fn(param.data)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 260, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 161, in _lazy_init
    _check_driver()
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 75, in _check_driver
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

Comment: How did you install torch? Did you have to specify where CUDA is? Did installation pick it up?

Comment: @tayfun I installed torch using the command in : pip3 install --no-cache-dir torchvision. current pip version is: 19.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**: The error came up because, the program code was ran inside a virtual machine (VMWare; OS: Ubuntu 18.04; Native System OS: Windows 10), in which driver for graphic was missing (As it's not possible to install graphic driver inside a virtual machine).

This page is a good guide for installing cuda in Ubuntu : https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-to-install-CUDA-9-2-on-Ubuntu-18-04-1184/